# h2 database access to test data from separate threads

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, h2

My *Integration* Test scenario:

1. create a row in H2 database
2. `sleep(50000ms)` (in the meantime another thread is invoked thanks to spring configuration and this thread should find row created in point 1. and update this row)
3. expect a row from point 1. has been updated by thread mentioned in point 2.

This scenario tests both - the configuration & implementation. And this is what I want to achieve.

I am using H2 database in all my tests so decided to use it here as well. When debugging the test scenario I discovered that new thread invoked during `sleep` - connects to the DB but doesn't find the row created. I went through H2 documentation and I started using:

```
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.194/h2-1.4.194.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -web -browser -tcpAllowOthers -tcpPort 9092 -webPort 8082
```

and the connection string:

```
DB_URL=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/~/test2
```

and the config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
      p:url="${DB_URL}"
      p:username="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}" p:password="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}"/>

<util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.fridayweekend.lottery.model"
      p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

NOTE: I already played a bit with ddl-auto - I tried to create schema at firs dry-run and then only validate it (to preven re-creation) but it didn't helped.

I can inspect the database via `H2 Web Console`. I see that the Schema is created (based on my Java-annotated Model), but no data is there (even during `sleep` or during debug breakpoint).

On the other hand - when I add the data (from the 1st scenario point) manually - I can debug that the second thread see it and update it correctly, then the test succeed. Data originated from the second thread is persisted and I can see it even after test suite finishes.

What should I do that the data originated from the main (@Test-annotated) thread be visible to the second thread?

PS. I think this is not relevant, but the "second" thread is invoked like that:

```
    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">${imap.protocol}</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">${imap.debug}</prop>
</util:properties>
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                              store-uri="${imap.uri}"
                              channel="recieveEmailChannel"
                              should-delete-messages="false"
                              should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                              auto-startup="true"
                              java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="${imap.poolerSecondsDelay}" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="emailReceiverService" method="receive"/>
```

so basicaly - it calls method `receive` of `emailReceiverService` bean. Of course - I ensured that the method is invoked (by sending an email to the inbox) - but, as I said- I do not think that the way the second thread is being created is relevan. Basically speaking - it is invoked by Spring configuration (spring configuration is passed to test method via

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/test-lottery-context.xml", "classpath:spring/test-sms-context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class QueueServiceImplIntegrationTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root issue there: *Transactions*!

My test was extending `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests` so the transaction scope was whole `@Test` annotated method. I changed my test to extend simply `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` - and then transactions' scope was narrowed to particular Service method (I am talking about regular MVC pattern) invoked from the `@Test` annotated method. Thats solved my issue.

Cheers!